# In Spring boot JWT Plus Oauth2, TokenStore findTokensByClientId(clientId) returns blank array (I want active tokens)

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I implemented spring boot with jwt plus oauth2 (In memory).

Here tokens are located in memory rather than database.

But when i use `tokenStore.findTokensByClientId(clientId)` then it returns blank array in below case

Example

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


    static final String CLIEN_ID = "vishvas-client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "$2a$10$kfH4W.jyBuqvX5TLu.OfbOEUtScm4V9FEUDvGI8AWPaqObUOQ7HJ2"; // vishvas-secret
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 12 * 60 * 60; // 12 hour
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 24 * 60 * 60; // 24 hour

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("as466gf");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        //  return new InMemoryTokenStore();   // Success : working but same access token generated every time. i want different access tokens
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter()); // Error :  tokenStore.findTokensByClientId(clientId) returns blank

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer.inMemory().withClient(CLIEN_ID).secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST).accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/tokens")
public class TokensEndpointController {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @CrossOrigin
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> findAllActiveSessions(@RequestParam String clientId,
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        try {

            String username = httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName();

            Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens = tokenStore.findTokensByClientId(clientId);
            List<String> tokenValues = tokens.stream().map(OAuth2AccessToken::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println("tokenValues : " + tokenValues); // Blank array

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseWrapperDTO(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK,
                    httpServletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE).toString(),
                    "Tokens got successfully.", tokenValues));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity(
                    new ResponseErrorDTO(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                            MethodUtils.getApiPathFromHttpServletRequest(httpServletRequest), e.getMessage()),
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

Example explanation:

1. In `tokenStore()` method, if I use  `return new InMemoryTokenStore();` then i can get all tokens successfully using api (http://localhost:8080/api/tokens?clientId=vishvas-client), but every time same access token is generated
2. In `tokenStore()` method, if I use `return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());` then api (http://localhost:8080/api/tokens?clientId=vishvas-client) returns blank array. (Problem with 2nd point, can't get tokens)

Comment: You accepted Denoxus'a answer, but that doesn't answer your question *I want all active tokens*, right? It only answers the question why don't you get all tokens. Next time it would be nice to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In the first configuration " **InMemoryTokenStore** " :

   - Is the **standard oauth2 token generation method**, mean that **one token will be generated** for **each user** and it will be **stored** ( so when you ask the authorize server for a client's tokens it will fetch for it not generating ) , until the token will **expire** then another token will be generated

> That's why you are getting the same token every time, but when this token will expire the authorize server will generate another one

2. In the second configuration " **JwtTokenStore** " :

   - Is the standard **oauth2  jwt token generation method**, mean that every time your ask for a token the authorize server will generate a token for you and **doesn't stored** it in memory
   - At this point if you are using JWT token, the server need to be stateless mean that no token storage or user information storage because JWT token are **self-contained** no need for the server to store token or user information

> That's why you are getting different token every time, but an empty list

you can check **JwtTokenStore** class in this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtTokenStore.java) at **Line 162**, you will find that by default is giving an Empty List

So for standar configuration you should use **JwtTokenStore**

Comment: Nice way to put.!